# Как упорядочить содержимое текстового файла по номеру в строке?

Tags: c#, .net, строки, файлы, файловый-ввод-вывод

Задача - дан текстовый файл, в нём содержится таблица вида:

```
    №           Серия       Наименование        Дополнение

    1           677492      12Тм 54             Допол

    1           Привет      76                  1з

    7           654         Это                 Твоё

    2           Тестовое    -=-=-=              СимволыИлиНет?

    0           Задание     ЉµЉ                 1787 - ?

    2147483747  Удачи       На полях            Правосудия
```

Вопрос - как упорядочить строки по номеру? 
Мой код:

```
public static void SortLines()
    {
        var str = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\c#\ТестовоеЗадание\Задание3.txt");

        var headerFromTestFile = str.Take(2);

        var sortTXT = str.Skip(2).Take(str.Length - 2)
            .Where(x => x != "")
            //.GroupBy(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(0)))
            .GroupBy(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(x.IndexOf("\t\t", 9))))
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .SelectMany(g => g);
        var str2 = str.Skip(str.Length - 1);

        File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\c#\ТестовоеЗадание\Задание3.txt", headerFromTestFile.Concat(sortTXT).Concat(str2));
    }
```

При такой реализации ругается, что входная строка имела не верный формат.

Comment: Строки начинаются с двух табов в текстовом файле с таблицей. Здесь они не много по-другому вставились, отредактировал вручную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выбираете подстроку (`x.Substring(x.IndexOf("\t\t", 9))`) от какого-то знака табуляции до конца строки, что несколько странно. Чтобы поиск работал через `Substring` нужно найти как начальную, так и конечную позиции номера в строке.

По-моему, номер проще искать с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
var sortTXT = str.Skip(2).Take(str.Length - 2)
            .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            .OrderBy(line => long.Parse(Regex.Match(line, "[0-9]+").Value));
```

Выражение `[0-9]+` найдет первое число в строке.

Не совсем понял для чего используется `str2`. Если файл всегда заканчивается строкой с 2147483747, и бо́льшего номера в файле нет, то можно обойтись без нее. Если же там в конце какой-то подвал, то тогда для `sortText` нужно брать `str.Length -3` строк.

Дополнение: если нужно после каждой строки оставлять пустую строку, то можно добавить к строкам знак переноса после сортировки:

```
var sortTXT = str.Skip(2).Take(str.Length - 2)
            .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            .OrderBy(line => long.Parse(Regex.Match(line, "[0-9]+").Value))
            .Select(line => line+Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Я пытался в строке x найти подстроку и при помощи IndexOf определить начало и конец этой подстроки. Смутили эти два таба в начале строки и запутался. По str2 - насколько я вижу и понимаю это задание, то файл может заканчиваться строкой 2147483747 и нет. А если сохранять пустые строки, то как будет выглядеть сортировка? Нужно просто убрать Where?

Comment: @Genas Если заканчивается 2147483747, то она и так попадет в конец, тогда `str2` не нужна. Если пустые строки чередуются, то лучше их добавить после сортировки, при записи файла, дабы не усложнять сортировку. Если они расположены неравномерно, и их нужно именно поставить на старые места, то задача немного усложнится и потребуется доп. параметр для сортировки. Если убрать `Where`, то нужно в `OrderBy` учесть, что строка может быть пустой.

Comment: Можете показать примерную реализацию чередования пустых строк?

Comment: @Genas Добавил простенький вариант в конец вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо, Вам большое за помощь!))))

Comment: @Genas Пожалуйста! Рад что помогло.

Comment: @Genas Что-то вы галочку поставили, потом сняли.

Comment: Сорри! Обновил страница - она серая, поставил ещё раз и получается отменил. Теперь точно всё в порядке.